# <embed> a PDF delivered from PHP

Tags: php, pdf, embed

I am trying to embed a PDF on a site, but I want the PDF delivered through a PHP file. I have pdf.php

```
$file = '/path/to/foo.pdf';
$filename = 'bar.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

and in embedhere.php I have tried

```
<embed type='application/pdf' src="pdf.php"/>
```

and

```
<embed type='application/pdf' src="https://full.url/pdf.php"/>
```

I have tried the same things with an iframe and an object tag.

When I navigate directly to pdf.php I get a full screen pdf, but in embedhere.php, I get the space for the embed (object,iframe) tag, but it is empty. Firefox inspect element shows

```
<embed type="application/pdf" src="pdf.php">
 #document
  <html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
  </html>
 </html>
</embed>
```

The second `</html>` is not a typo.

The goal is to embed a PDF specific to a user, preferably with `<embed>` or `<object>` without it taking up the whole page. Why does it come up blank?

Comment: you probably need to remove the header calls, if its embeded, or they would be ok if you used an iframe

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. What PDF file and browser are you using? Did you use a closing php tag `?>`  anywhere in your PDF generator or the include files it uses? Often times a line break in you script will be rendered as text, so it is best to omit the closing php tag. For context I used `<embed src="/pdf.php" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>` Also ensure the `$file` exists using `if (file_exists($file)) { //.. readfile($file); }

Comment: Thanks fyrye. It does work in Chrome, but Firefox still won't display. I'm using a static PDF file on the server machine for testing. More digging makes me think it is an NGINX config issue. The console is popping up X-Frame-Options errors and Strict-Transport-Security errors. I can't tell if Chrome is not having the errors, or if it is just ignoring them and I can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fyrye for pointing out the line break issue. The trouble turned out to be an NGINX configuration issue. I don't know why Chrome was able to display the PDF, but Firefox was complaining because NGINX had been configured with

```
X-Frame-Origins DENY;
```

instead of

```
X-Frame-Origins SAMEORIGIN;
```

Changing that and restarting NGINX resolved the issue.